# How to create custom scrolling always start from bottom

Tags: blackberry

Here I am creating a screen for chatting that contains a top bar, custom vertical scroll manager, an `Editfield` to send messages and a **send** button.

Now I create a message layout: it has `VerticalFieldManager` and it contains `EditField` that is focusable and readonly, and two `LabelField`s for name and date. This vertical field manager is created dynamically depending on the number of chat messages. This is all laid out in custom scroll.

I need scrolling to start from the bottom of the screen. Right now, it works from top of the screen.

At the bottom on the screen I have a `BasicEditField` and **send** button.

Each 7 seconds, I refresh the page and when refreshing the page, I recreate the whole layout. So I need to retain focus on the `BasicEditField` whenever my page refreshes. And I also want the scrolling to work reversed.

Here my vertical scroll manager class

```java
public class VerticalScrollManager extends VerticalFieldManager implements
    ScrollChangeListener {


public VerticalScrollManager() {
    this(VERTICAL_SCROLL | NO_VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR|DOWNWARD, Integer.MAX_VALUE, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
}

public VerticalScrollManager(int w, int h) {
    this(VERTICAL_SCROLL | NO_VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR|DOWNWARD, w, h);
}

public VerticalScrollManager(long style) {
    this(style, Integer.MAX_VALUE, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
}

public VerticalScrollManager(long style, int w, int h) {
    super(style);
    maxVisibleHeight = h;
    maxVisibleWidth = w;

    setScrollListener(this);
}




protected void sublayout(int w, int h) {

    isScrolling = ((getStyle() & VERTICAL_SCROLL) == VERTICAL_SCROLL);

    int scrollbarWidth = isScrolling ? SCROLLBAR_WIDTH + SCROLLBAR_LEFT_MARGIN + SCROLLBAR_RIGHT_MARGIN : 0;

    visibleHeight = Math.min(h, maxVisibleHeight);
    visibleWidth = Math.min(w, maxVisibleWidth);

    int myWidth = visibleWidth - scrollbarWidth;
    super.sublayout(myWidth, visibleHeight);


    visibleHeight = getHeight();
    totalHeight = getVirtualHeight();
    visibleWidth = getWidth() + scrollbarWidth;

    setExtent(visibleWidth, visibleHeight);

    setVirtualExtent(visibleWidth, totalHeight);

    isScrolling = (visibleHeight < totalHeight);


    if (isScrolling) {
        sliderHeight = visibleHeight * visibleHeight / totalHeight;
        sliderHeight = Math.max(sliderHeight, 1);    // show at least one pixel!

        sliderXPosition = visibleWidth - SCROLLBAR_WIDTH - SCROLLBAR_RIGHT_MARGIN;

    }
}




public void scrollChanged(Manager mgr, int newX, int newY) {
if (mgr == this) {
       invalidate(newX + sliderXPosition, newY, SCROLLBAR_WIDTH + SCROLLBAR_RIGHT_MARGIN, getVisibleHeight());

}
}
```

}

and here my screen that handle ui and functionality

```java
public class ChatScreen extends MainScreen implements FieldChangeListener, FocusChangeListener {



    class MainTask implements Runnable
    {

        public MainTask()
        {}

        public void run() {

            try
            {
                if(textMsg.getText().equals(""))
                {   
                    IssueHTTPPostL();
                }
                else
                {
                    IssueHTTPPostChat(textMsg.getText());
                }
                UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                    public void run() {
                        if(replyCode.equalsIgnoreCase("success"))
                        {   




                            if(chatMsgData!=null && chatMsgData.length>0 )
                            {

                                for( int i=0; i<chatMsgData.length; i++)
                                {


                                    final String name = chatMsgData[i].name;
                                    final String email = chatMsgData[i].email;
                                    final String date = chatMsgData[i].date;
                                    final String msg = chatMsgData[i].message;
                                    final String vappUser = chatMsgData[i].vappUser;

                                    if(chatMsgData[i].isReply.equals("0"))
                                    {   

                                        vfm = new VerticalFieldManager(VerticalFieldManager.FIELD_RIGHT)
                                        {
                                            protected void paintBackground(Graphics g) 
                                            {

                                                g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                                                g.fillRoundRect(30, 0, getWidth()-30, getHeight(), 12, 12);
                                                g.setColor(0X626262);
                                                g.drawRoundRect(30, 0, getWidth()-30, getHeight(), 12, 12);
                                                //g.drawBitmap(0,0,getWidth(),getHeight(),imgRight,0,0);
                                            }   

                                        };

                                        lblName = new LabelField(name, LabelField.FIELD_LEFT|DrawStyle.LEFT)
                                        {
                                            protected void paint(Graphics g) 
                                            {
                                                g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                                                super.paint(g);
                                            };
                                        };

                                        if(name.equals("")||name.equals("Name"))
                                        {
                                            lblName.setText(email);
                                        }

                                        lblDate = new LabelField(date, LabelField.FIELD_RIGHT|DrawStyle.RIGHT);
                                        lblDate.setFont(font.derive(Font.PLAIN, dateFontSize));
                                        lblName.setFont(font.derive(Font.BOLD, nameFontSize));
                                        JustifiedHorizontalFieldManager hfm = new JustifiedHorizontalFieldManager(lblName, lblDate, true);


                                        hfm.setMargin(10, 10, 10, 50);

                                            lblMsg = new EditField(EditField.FOCUSABLE|EditField.READONLY)
                                            {
                                                protected void paint(Graphics g) 
                                                {
                                                    g.setColor(0x626262);
                                                    super.paint(g);
                                                };
                                            };


                                        lblMsg.setText(msg);
                                        lblMsg.setMargin(10, 10, 10, 50);
                                        lblMsg.setFont(font.derive(Font.PLAIN, msgFontSize));
                                        vfm.add(hfm);

                                        vfm.add(lblMsg);
                                        vfm.setMargin(10, 20, 10, 0);
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {

                                        vfm = new VerticalFieldManager(VerticalFieldManager.FIELD_LEFT)
                                        {
                                            protected void paintBackground(Graphics g) 
                                            {
                                                g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                                                g.fillRoundRect(0, 0, getWidth()-30, getHeight(), 12, 12);
                                                g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                                                g.drawRoundRect(0, 0, getWidth()-30, getHeight(), 12, 12);
                                                //g.drawBitmap(0,0,getWidth(),getHeight(),imgLeft,0,0);
                                            }
                                        };


                                        lblName = new LabelField(vappUser, LabelField.FIELD_LEFT|DrawStyle.LEFT)
                                        {
                                            protected void paint(Graphics g) 
                                            {
                                                g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                                                super.paint(g);
                                            };
                                        };

                                        if(name.equals("")||name.equals("Name"))
                                        {
                                            lblName.setText(email);
                                        }

                                        lblDate = new LabelField(date, LabelField.FIELD_RIGHT|DrawStyle.RIGHT)
                                        {
                                            protected void paint(Graphics g) 
                                            {
                                                g.setColor(0X626262);
                                                super.paint(g);
                                            };
                                        };
                                        lblDate.setFont(font.derive(Font.PLAIN, dateFontSize));
                                        lblName.setFont(font.derive(Font.BOLD, nameFontSize));
                                        JustifiedHorizontalFieldManager hfm = new JustifiedHorizontalFieldManager(lblName, lblDate, true);

                                        //hfm.setMargin("top", "right", "bottom", "left");
                                        hfm.setMargin(10, 50, 10, 10);


                                            lblMsg = new EditField(EditField.FOCUSABLE|EditField.READONLY)
                                            {
                                                protected void paint(Graphics g) 
                                                {
                                                    g.setColor(0x626262);
                                                    super.paint(g);
                                                };
                                            };


                                        lblMsg.setText(msg);
                                        lblMsg.setMargin(10, 40, 10, 10);
                                        lblMsg.setFont(font.derive(Font.PLAIN, msgFontSize));
                                        vfm.add(hfm);

                                        vfm.add(lblMsg);

                                        vfm.setMargin(10, 10, 20, 0);



                                    }


                                    vsm.add(vfm);


                                }   

                            }
                            add(vsm);

                            add(sendHfm);
                        }

                        else
                        {

                            timer.cancel();
                            UiApplication.getUiApplication().popScreen(ChatScreen.this);
                            UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(new ChatListScreen());
                        }
                    }
                });

            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {e.printStackTrace();}
        }

    }









}
```

[image]

Comment: If you show us the **code** you use to build this UI, it's easier for us to give you specific solutions.  Thanks.

Comment: ok i will provide this please give me ur email id

Comment: No, I mean post some of the code above.  If you click the **edit** link, you can add more to your original question.  That way, others can see the code, too, and give you help, too.

Comment: I have posted my code please have a look

Comment: Nate now read my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you have one `VerticalFieldManager` in the middle of the screen (below the Top Bar, and above the Send button).  You would like to have that manager start at the bottom of its content.  Right?

For that, try using

```java
vsm.setVerticalScroll(vsm.getVirtualHeight());
```

where `vsm` is that vertical field manager that contains the old read-only messages.

Anytime something happens (like a page refresh) that might take focus off your `BasicEditField`, you can get it back with

```java
textMsg.setFocus();
```

where `textMsg` is the edit field.  Obviously, in order for this to work, you need to keep `vsm` and `textMsg` as member variables, instead of just creating them as local variables and adding them to your screen with `add()`.

Comment: I am not able to set focus on bef when page refresh.

Comment: @Newts, Why not? Are you saying that you tried it, and it didn't work?

Comment: @Newts, I can't help you with the information you've given me.  *"I try this its not working"* is not useful information.  **What** did you try?  **Where** did you put the code? **What** do you see?  Be specific.  We can't read your mind.  You have to describe your problem well to get solutions here.

Comment: I want to creating layout like bbm. In this layout shows like my image.

Comment: I want to creating layout like bbm. In this layout shows like my image. I create VerticalScrollManager class for custom scrolling. and I create only mid part of screen scrollable but it always start scrolling from top to bottom so I need to start from bottom to top.

Comment: Thanks alot!! I have not place them at right position. Many Many Thanks :)